# Placing odd numbers in consecutive elements of list: Python 3.2

Tags: python, list, function, numbers

I'm in an introductory Python course.  I'm taking a practice final and I don't know exactly what to do for a question.  It asks:

Complete the following method that places odd numbers found in the string s in consecutive elements of the list x.

```
def assign(s):
    length = _____
    x = _____*[0]
    index = 0
    for j in range(_____):
        digit = int(s[j])  #convert to int digit
        if _____: #test for odd number
            x[_____] = digit
            __________
    print("The odd numbers are")
    for j in range(index):
        print(x[j])
```

I don't know if it's the way it's worded but I have no clue how to go about answering this.  My best guess would be:

```
def assign(s):
    length = len(s)
    x = length*[0]
    index = 0
    for j in range(s):
        digit = int(s[j])  #convert to int digit
        if _____: #test for odd number
            x[_____] = digit
            __________
    print("The odd numbers are")
    for j in range(index):
        print(x[j])
```

I have no clue how to continue, or if I'm even starting it off right.  I can't change anything that's already there, I can only fill in the blanks, and they all have to be filled in.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
def assign(s):
    length = len(s)
    x = length*[0]
    index = 0
    for j in range(length):
        digit = int(s[j])  #convert to int digit
        if digit % 2: #test for odd number
            x[index] = digit
            index += 1

    print("The odd numbers are")
    for j in range(index):
        print(x[j])
```

You got the beginning right. An key point is that variable `index` points to the next odd number that should be added to list `x`.

---

Note, however, that the template that was provided to you is horrible: it completely goes against the spirit of Python. It looks like C code forced into Python; this is not good practice, as Python offers much more powerful data structures than C.  Here is **a Pythonic version**:

```
def assign(input_string):
    odd_digits = []
    for char in input_string:
        digit = int(char)  # Convert to integer
        if digit % 2:  # If the digit is odd
            odd_digits.append(digit)
    print("The odd digits are", *odd_digits, sep='\n')  # or: ("The odd digits are", odd_digits)
```

The main difference is that you have *fewer variables*: the code is more legible, one has to keep fewer variables in mind when reading the code. The variables that have disappeared are essentially indexes: they are often not needed (indexes are important in C because C is "close to the metal": it is close to machine language, which requires indexes). As a consequence, the need for keeping track of the `length` of the input string disappears.

You also have less cruft: in the original version, list `x` contained many `0` that were essentially useless (slower code, which is also harder to make sense of). Essentially, *Python list* `x` was forced to be like a *C array*: the variable number of odd digits in the string call for a list (variable size), not for an array (fixed size).

Also, the fact that the code is shorter makes is faster to read, and to write!

---

As suggested by Jon, an **even more Pythonic version** consists in using list comprehensions:

```
def assign(input_string):
    odd_digits = [char for char in input_string if int(char) % 2]  # or: if char in '13579'
    print("The odd digits are", *odd_digits, sep='\n')  # or: ("The odd digits are", odd_digits)
```

This is a good example of why Python code is so much faster to write and read than C code.

Comment: It worked, thank you!  What is += though?  I've never learned that.

Comment: `index += 1` is equivalent to `index = index + 1` but is more legible: you know right away that the value of `index` is simply incremented by some amount.

Comment: So, this is basically `[int(ch) for ch in input_string if ch in '13579']` ?

Comment: Shouldn't your list comprehension be `[char for char in input_string if int(char) % 2]`?

Comment: Just curious... How is print("The odd digits are", *odd_digits, sep='\n'), valid python code? It gives me SyntaxError: invalid syntax for the * and the 'sep' using the interpreter and python 2.7.1. --Thanks

Comment: @vkontori: This `print()` is Python 3's `print` function (as in the original question). You can get it in Python 2 by doing, at the beginning of your program, `from __future__ import print_function`. Otherwise, the Python 2 equivalent would be `print "\n".join(["The odd digits are"] + odd_digits)`.